# C# PictureBox.Image DataBind to Object Image Property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a class `Employee` defined as this

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private Image photo;


     public Image Photo
     {
            get { return photo; }
            set { photo = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Photo")); }
     }


    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And this is my usage: i have a `PictureBox` control named as `pbPhoto` and its Image **has a default value** from my `Resources.Blank`, the property is databound to `Employee.Photo` property inside the `Page_Load` event.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
this.pbPhoto.DataBindings.Add("Image", employee, "Photo");
```

But it doesn't seems to work and i got this error message.

> Cannot format the value to the desired type.

Comment: The second parameter should contain an object, not a type

Comment: Please check the revised question.

Comment: I don't see where you actually set the Photo property. I guess you cannot set a binding to a property which returns null

Comment: If you dont want to assign an Image to the photo property of the employee yet then add an empty Image to the photo property in the constructor of the employee class like this for example:   this.photo = new Bitmap(1, 1);

Comment: This one solve my problem, the error occurred because of a null Photo Image property of the object. i just assigned a blank.png and it worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem based to [`Mono's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696813/c-sharp-picturebox-image-databind-to-object-image-property#comment62869673_37696813) above,

There are two different approach:

First, before binding `pbPhoto.Image` property to object `Photo` property you have to assign a default value to `employee.Photo` since we can't set a binding property which returns a `null` value.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.Photo = Resources.Blank; // Initial value.
this.pbPhoto.DataBindings.Add("Image", employee, "Photo");
```

The other one is to set `Photo` property initial value in the `Employee` constructor.

```
public Employee()
{
    this.Photo = Resources.Blank;
}
```

then you can proceed to this.

```
// During the program execution the Photo has an initial assigned value.
Employee employee = new Employee(); 
this.pbPhoto.DataBindings.Add("Image", employee, "Photo");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a very old WinForms data binding buggy behavior which is fixed by setting the [`Binding.FormattingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true` (unfortunately for "backward compatibility" by default it is `false`):

```
this.pbPhoto.DataBindings.Add("Image", employee, "Photo", true);
```

If you want to associate default value when the data source property is null, you can use the [`Binding.NullValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cts9y9k(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
this.pbPhoto.DataBindings.Add("Image", employee, "Photo", true,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Resources.Blank);
```

Comment: I just updated my question, this one partially solve my problem but my `PictureBox` has a default `Image` value and whenever i load the form the `Image` disappeared.

Comment: Ive got an error when converting the `employee.Photo` property to `byte[]`  `object reference not set to an instance of an object` but i can achieved the whole lot of this by simply assigning initial image to the `employee.Photo = Resources.Blank` based on @Mono suggestion in the question comment below.